# Google marker placement

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I currently have some code which when you press the submit button, a marker should be placed on a map according to the value that is in a drop down list box. I have made it so that the value in the drop down box will go into the URL via a GET form method for the PHP code and will also pass the value via parameter to the javascript function.

The problem I am having is that I have to press the submit button twice so that the marker will appear on the map. This is less then ideal and I am looking for some help to try fix this problem. Thanks.

This is the javascript function code:

```
function placeMarker(address) 
        {       
            // ... Set up map code here

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("universityMap"), myOptions);

            <?php
                $uniname = $_GET['uninames'];       

                //Get the Uni code according to the uni name
                $queryUniID = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT IdCode FROM universityid WHERE UniName = ?");
                $queryUniID->bind_param('s', $uniname);
                $queryUniID->execute();
                $queryUniID->bind_result($unicode);
                $queryUniID->fetch();
                $queryUniID->close();

                //Load the question data into relevant variables
                $queryQuestions = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT QuestionNo, Answered1, Answered2, Answered3, Answered4, Answered5 FROM nssdata WHERE UniID = ?");
            ?>

            address = address + ", UK";
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: address, 
                        draggable: false
                    });
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert(status);
                }
            });
        }
```

This is my html form:

```
        <form action="#" onsubmit="placeMarker(this.uninames.value)" method="get">
```

Comment: Are you attempting to batch-geocode universities based on a list of prepopulated addresses?

Comment: No, i'm only doing one geocode according to what is in the dropdown list when the search button is pressed

Comment: Why is there PHP code in the middle of your JS function?

Comment: its used to get the code for the uni from the database that I have set up. It will be used to load some data later on in the creation of my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should actually work, provided that your values are all within proper ranges. In testing a reduced version of this, I can type an address, click submit and markers show up right where they should be.

I have a few theories as to why you are clicking twice before seeing a result.

(1) **Lookup latency**: make sure to track geocoder states and give it ample time to perform.

(2) **Glitch**: In some map renderers, you sometimes need to cycle maps for a marker. For example, this set of successive calls: `marker.setMap( null ); marker.setMap( map );` will hide/show a marker and sometimes unglitch the display.

(3) **Submit interruption**: If the interface is more complex than you have stated and is possibly interfering, your form submit (#) probably needs to be prevented from submitting.  In other words, you must stop the browser from going to the # address after clicking submit so you can let JavaScript/ajax do its work.

Here's a reduced version of the form; note the **return(false)** part - it prevents browser address from changing to #.

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="placeMarker('adr');return( false );" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="id_address" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Note that I simplified this address to text; in my actual test I sent data this way:

`placeMarker(document.getElementById('id_address').value);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is very close to working now, the only problem is that by putting the return false into the on submit section, the address is never put into the url by the get method, which is causing the php to load the wrong data